# LiveUSB does not work

Tags: boot, software-installation, live-usb

I made a LiveUSB stick by following the instructions from this [site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

I booted to the LiveUSB with my other PC and got the Ubuntu installation screen with the following options:

- run from USB,
- install to hard disk,
- test memory,
- boot from first hard disk,
- advanced options and
- help

It gives me 5 seconds to choose before it just boots from USB, but if I hit any key, it freezes so I just let it run out of time and then it gives me a black screen that says loading:

```
/casper/vmlinuz........
loading /casper/initrd.lz..........ready
```

I don't know what to do. Pressing any key does not work. It's not loading or going anywhere. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

It can be booted from a FDD which is where it pops up and recognizes the USB, it just keeps giving me the same freezing problem. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, I open the burner, click on Ubuntu 12.04, then on the Ubuntu rar, then burn it to the USB, then pop it in, go to my boot manager, click on FDD to opening it, it gets to a screen with options on it, but if I hit anything it freezes. I haven't tried to Md5sum check it yet.

Comment: Do a [md5sum check](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of Your Ubuntu ISO image and check with the Download source. And Burn again to Usb Drive , i mean repeat the process.

Comment: Please describe the hardware specs of your PC in detail.
Can your PC work with LiveCD using CD drive?

Comment: Specs http://www.cnet.com/laptops/toshiba-satellite-l355-s7915/4507-3121_7-33744822.html

Comment: It can be booted from a FDD witch it where it pops up it recanizes the USB it just keeps giveing me the same freezing problem maybe im doing it wrong, i open the burner click on Umbutu 12.04 then on the umbutu rar and then burn it to the USB then pop it in go to my boot manager and click on FDD to opening it it gets to a sreen with options on it but if i hit anything it freez i havent try to Md5sum check it yet.

Comment: Can you rephrase your last paragraph? I'm not sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the official guide uses pen drive linux, I would recommend using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a live USB, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a PC just cant boot from USB. It might even *say* it can, but fail to. This would only happen with a computer that is a bit old.

If that is your case, you might use plop:
http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=16822